# Authenticate MembershipUser without password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

Is it possible to authenticate a MembershipUser without a password. I have gues user accounts and whihc have temporary passwords, however i do not required these users to actually login. I want to automatically authenticate them back on their userid.

Can this be done?

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(publicuser.UserName, false);
```

doesn't seem to actually authenticate them againsts the memebrship provider.

Comment: Why do you need to validate the user against the membership provider? Why isn't SetAuthCookie enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the ValidateUser defined in System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ApplicationServices:

```
protected override bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
```

Then you can check

`if ( IsAGuestAccount( userName ) ) return true;`